# Github Public Repo Login Requirements

Tags: github

I was looking through some of the deep learning repositories on [Github](https://github.com/) on my phone and for some reason the repository located at https://github.com/deepfakes/faceswap redirected me to a login page.

It opens normally on my laptop since I'm logged in on it, so it's obviously not private. Is there a setting for disabling anonymous access, or was it forced on by Github to try to track users who access that repository? It also contains `porn` in the readme so it may be some rudimentary attempt at censoring it (though there are no options for setting up an age in the profile options). I cannot find any documentation referencing this feature.